# Design of virtual trial room

Tags: c++, python, opengl, graphics, blender

As a part of my masters project I proposed to build a virtual trial room application intended for retail clothing stores. Currently its meant to be used directly in store though it may be extended for online stores as well.

This application will show customers how a selected apparel would look on them by showing it on their 3D replica on screen.

It involves 3 steps

1. Sizing up the customer
2. Building customer replica 3D humanoid model
3. Apply simulated cloth on the model

My question is about the feasibility of the project and choice of framework.
Can this be achieved in real time using a normal Desktop computer? If yes what would be appropriate framework ( hardware, software, programming language etc ) for this purpose?

On the work I have done till now, I was planning to achieve above steps in following ways

for step 1 : option a) Two cameras for front and side views or
             option b) 1 Kinect or 2 Kinect for complete 3D data

for step 2: either use makehuman (http://www.makehuman.org/) code to build a customised 3D model using above data or build everything from scratch, unsure about the framework.

for step 3: Just need few cloth samples, so thought of building simulated clothes in blender.

Currently I have just the vague idea about different pieces but I am not sure of how to develop complete application.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically this can be achieved in real time. Many usefull algorithms for video tracking, stereo vision and 3d recostruction are available in [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) library. But it's very difficult to build robust solution. For example, you'll probably need to track human body which moves frame to frame and perform pose estimation (OpenCV contains POSIT algorithm), however it's not trivial to eliminate noise in resulting objects coordinates. For inspiration see a [nice work](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/) on video tracking.

You might want to choose another way, simplify some things, avoid complicated stuff do things less dynamicaly and estimate only clothes size and approximate human location. I this case most likely you will create something usefull and interesting.

I've lost link to one online fiting room where hands and body detection implemented. Using Kinnect solves many problems. But If for some reason you won't use it then AR(augmented reality) helps you (yet another [fitting room)](http://www.dressingroomonline.com/)