# Best way to automatically model 3D human

Tags: model, 3d, kinect

I want to automatically model 3D human from given anthropometric measurements (basic sizes, height, waist, chest diameter etc). Is there any tool/library that can let me do it automatically or a quick way to build it. I want it to be completely automated with zero human interaction as it is supposed to be the part of a overall module. (see below)

[Design of virtual trial room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624936/design-of-virtual-trial-room)

I checked makehuman, spent few days with it, its amazing but again too much interactive, I tried to make it automatic but failed. Any suggestion would be much appreciated

Comment: If you're using a Kinect, the depth information is already there. Can't you use it to obtain your model directly?

Comment: I am also fumbling to use Kinect, I brought two of them to capture 3D point cloud of human figure and then convert it into a mesh, but till now unable to make much use of it, even with web available resources on Kinect.

Comment: The Kinect approach will make a fun project, but it will be very hard to get good results. Especially if you want any form of accuracy. This might become important when combined with physical simulation and if you're interested in evaluating garment fit. Even the result of dedicated body scanners often (or always) needs to be manually cleaned up to be used. If all you want though is to get a model and some cloth, and you don't care about accurate results but more about the experience and fun, then go for it. :)

Comment: Hey, there's an official Kinect SDK from Microsoft now. See if this is useful for you: http://channel9.msdn.com/series/KinectSDKQuickstarts

Answer (score 5):

I think that for a ready to use solution [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/) might still be your best bet. I have not enough experience with it to give your advice on how to solve your problems, but you might ask the community.

Another solution (although definitely more involved) would be to develop your own template model with deformation information. You might check out the work of Kasap et al. [here](http://www.miralab.ch//repository/papers/428.pdf) for some inspiration. This work was specifically created to be used in a similar scenario as you describe in your earlier question.